# Access API through GraphQL - loop through multiple pages with Promise.all

Tags: node.js, rest

I am able to fetch data from the API, and I can loop through the multiple pages of data if there are multiple pages. However, to speed it up, I would like to try and retrieve multiple pages at a time.

But I can't get this code to work.

```
async people() {
  // https://swapi.co/api/people/

  // The API returns 10 items per page
  const perPage = 10

  let promises = []

  // Start with an empty array and add the results from each API call
  let allResults = []

  // Get first page and total number of pages 
  // based on total number of results (data.count)
  let people = await fetch(`https://swapi.co/api/people`)
  let data = await people.json()
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(data.count / perPage)

  // Add results to array
  allResults = allResults.concat(data.results)

  // If the total results is greater than the results per page, 
  // get the rest of the results and add to the aLLResults array
  if (data.count > perPage) {
    for (let page = 2; page <= totalPages; page++) {
      promises.push(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          people = fetch(`https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=${page}`).
          then(response => {
            data = response.json()
          },
          response => {
            allResults = allResults.concat(response.results)
          }
        )
      })
    )
  }

  return Promise.all(promises)
}
return allResults
```

},

Answer (score 0):

```
          then(response => {
            data = response.json()
          },
          response => {
            allResults = allResults.concat(response.results)
          }
```

In this section, the `allResults = allResults.concat(response.results)` is only triggered as the error-handling callback, equivalent to a `.catch((err) => { ... })`. Is that what you intend?
`